# error adding provate repo on codecov `Account activation required. To view this page your account must be activated.`

Tags: github, codecov

I'm using codecov without issue in a `public repo`, ([this one](https://github.com/iapicca/yak_packages))
with the same account I'm trying to add a `private repo`
but when I try to add the repo in the codecov website I get the error below

```
Account activation required.
To view this page your account must be activated.

Please contact a GitHub Organization Administrator or Codecov Administrator(*) to activate your account.
```

> `*` = useless link to my settings

here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMvxY.png)

If my memory doesn't fail me the only action I've taken on github
was to add a `token` found in the codecov settings, so afterward

I've just double-checked the [docs](https://docs.codecov.io/docs/quick-start#getting-started), but I don't see what I'm missing
can anyone point me in the right direction

--- edit 1 ---

[permission on github are granted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBCO1.png)

--- edit 2 ---

I just noticed that when I log in "Syncing GitHub Teams" runs forever [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCR0c.png)

Comment: you can try to grant permission using https://codecov.io/login/github?private=t&redirect=github/iapicca checkout [this](https://codecov.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/43000593950-cannot-access-repository-on-codecov)

Comment: the first link just send me to the list of my repo (where I see only the one I linked in the first line of my question) the second shows my settings on github that I added with the link `permission on github are granted`